# "Priority only" as default mode - Marshmallow

Tags: notifications, 6.0-marshmallow

When I try to change the "Notifications mode" using the volume key, it always defaults to "Alarms only" mode, but I would like this to be set as "Priority only".

I know I can swipe down to access "Do not disturb" and set the "Priority only" mode but I want to do it with volume keys

Is there any way to set "Priority only" as default mode when using Volume keys

Comment: I wish I could help you. 5.0 and above have terrible volume settings.

Comment: @beeshyams I wasn't able to set the priority mode as default mode yet. Can you please share step by step. I am using Nexus 5. Here is another question on this topic http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/150748/how-to-change-default-do-not-disturb-to-priority-only

Comment: @beeshyams  Sorry but every time I press my volume button down, I don't see any way to reach the priority mode. Can you please give me the direction to do this?

Comment: Also, as you told "silencing the volume + being on Vibrate + further decreasing volume = priority mode" is what I am looking for...

Comment: @beeshyams sorry for the delay... I will try this by the weekend and let you know. Thanks and appreciate your effort and help

Answer (score 4):

*Alarm mode*  is activated when Vol is decreased progressively reaching *silence* first, next *vibrate* and on further decreasing the volume (watch closely and you would notice these steps). OP has [clarified](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132878/priority-only-as-default-mode-marshmallow#comment210375_132878) that this the behavior expected except that desired end mode should be *Priority mode* instead of *Alarm mode*

Since we are talking of changing the default behavior of OS, one way could be to root the device and tweak or use an app. [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) may be preferred option, since it doesn't involve rooting & modding. Many apps are available. I prefer using MacroDroid , since it is free (upto 5 macros) and easy to learn. To understand how MacroDroid works and required settings (app guides you through the settings - make sure from the app settings you activate *ignore battery optimisations*, my [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133394/131553). The drawback of automation approach is that it won't **perfectly replicate** the expected behavior and has snags, which are mentioned at  end

You would need two macros for this

First macro would look like this (Triggers / Actions / Constraints are added by **+**)

### Macro : Vol Silent / Vibrate (name of macro )

**Trigger** : *Volume Button Pressed* → *Volume Down* → *Update Volume*

**Actions**:

1. *Set MacroDroid Variable* → *New Variable* →*Create New Variable*→ Give it any name (here *ring*) and set type to *Integer* → Set (variable name) → *Value = 0*
2. *If Clause* → *Conditions **+*** → *Ringer Volume* → *Vibrate or Silent* . Press this *If clause* and choose *Add Child Action*. Next,  *Set Macrodroid Variable*,  choose the variable name (step 1) and set it to 1

**Constraints**:  No Constraints

**Logic:** We need to identify when *silence or vibrate* is reached by <kbd>Vol Dn</kbd>  . In the first action we named a variable and set it to 0 and in the second action, we set a flag (MacroDroid variable =1 ) to indicate that *silence or vibrate* is reached. Not specifying any Constraints means we want the macro to always run

In the next macro, we make sure that if the Volume is further decreased from *silence or vibrate* state, we set it to *Priority Mode*. To ensure that it happens only when this state is reached, we use the flag as constraint and re-initialize the variable to 0

### Macro : Set Priority Mode (name of macro )

**Trigger** : *Volume Button Pressed* → *Volume Down* → *Update Volume*

**Actions**:

1. *Set Priority Mode* → *Priority*
2. Set MacroDroid Variable (name you chose, here it is *ring*) → *Value = 0*

**Constraints**:  *MacroDroid Variable (ring)* → *Value = 1*

[image]
[image]

OK , I had mentioned that it isn't perfect, mainly because you are trying to override default OS behavior without rooting and modding. So, here are the glitches :

1. If you **pause** decreasing volume on reaching *Silence / Vibrate*, or if you are on vibrate and decrease volume further - **it won't work**
2. Sometimes , even if you decrease volume smoothly without pausing, you would still see *Alarm mode* instead of *Priority mode*. Reading the app logs indicates that this is because both the micros require a few milliseconds to kick in and by then OS has done it's job !  Workaround is to increase the volume a bit and then decrease it, maybe a couple of times allowing the app to do it's job
3. From *Priority Mode*, when you increase the volume, it still displays the same status (unlike in alarm mode) , so you need to manually click *End Now*

Comment: +1 for amazing effort, totally looks like it works (haven't tried though)