# How To Change Default "Do Not Disturb" To Priority Only

Tags: notifications, 6.0-marshmallow

I've experimented and looked all over for a solution to this, but it doesn't seem like anyone has wanted to do it yet.

I'm running Android 6.0 Marshmellow on a Droid Turbo 2. When I use the volume buttons to silence my phone, it defaults to Alarm Only, but I want it to default to Priority Only. Is this possible? It would save me the tiny pain of going into my Quick Settings Menu each time I want to switch to Priority Only.

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly duplicate. See answer http://android.stackexchange.com/q/132878/131553