# Is there any way to reduce minimum brightness without root?

Tags: root-access, screen-brightness

I want to reduce the minumum brightness of the screen of my Toshiba Excite Pro tablet. This is a tablet which (as far as I can tell) is essentially impossible to root, but I want to change the brightness of the screen, the value of which is stored in a file in the /sys/ directory of the tablet's filesystem. I want to change the value stored in this file from "35", to, say "10". Is there any way I can do this? For example:

- a way of temporarily getting permissions to alter this file without fully rooting the device
- an app which does not require root which reduces brightness beyond the default minimum
- or if there is, indeed a way to root this device now, that would be good.

Note: I'm not looking for an app which will put a filter over the screen to darken it; I want to turn down the screen as it's the biggest consumer of energy and I want to increase battery life.

Edit: I want to change this file as 35 is the *minimum* screen brightness. The system settings for some reason have a very narrow range of allowed brightnesses.

Comment: I do not think that without root it is possible

Comment: Not possible . See https://android.stackexchange.com/q/133382/131553

Answer (score 0):

#### Impossible.

I used to have your idea and I gave it a try, but to no avail. I rooted my phone and did the following

```
echo 1 > brightness
```

... but it seems to be identical to its lowest value, which is in my case, 20.

The mininum brightness is something in the **screen's firmware**, which is even **beyond the Linux kernel**. You can't change it unless you flash a custom firmware to your screen, and it will almost surely destroy it, so don't attempt to do so.