# Custom ring tone for callers who block their caller ID?

Tags: automation, ringtone, caller-id

How can I set a custom ringtone for callers who block their caller ID? I don't want the same ringtone for callers who don't block caller ID but are also not one of my contacts (otherwise, I could set a custom ringtone for all of my contacts and change the default ringtone).

**Device:** Moto X (2nd Generation) with Android 5.1, security patch level 2016-03-01

Answer (score 3):

Automation is the preferred option. Many apps are available. I prefer using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) , since it is free (upto 5 macros) and easy to learn. To understand how MacroDroid works and required **settings**,  my [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133394/131553)

---

**Edit:**   I overlooked a **correct** set of actions, my fault.  The earlier option of set ringtone  *reacts at the point where the phone rings*, at which point the phone has already started ringing - deleted that option. Sorry for that

What you could do is reduce the ringer volume to zero, increase the music volume and use the play sound action on the music stream for unknown callers with the incoming call trigger.

And add a corresponding macro to reverse the ringer volume for any caller *other than unknown*

Your macros would look like this

- **Unknown caller macro** (name of macro )

**Trigger**: *Call incoming* → *Select contact* →*Unknown Caller*

**Actions**:

1. *Volume Change* →

   - *Select Ringer (check the box)* and set *Volume* to zero using the sliding scale
   - *Select Music (check the box)* and set *Volume* to say 80 using the sliding scale ( can be adjusted to comfortable level later )
   - Click *OK*
2. *Play Stop/Sound* →

   - *Choose Sound* - The problem with choosing a sound option from the app choices is that it plays only for a short time and you may miss it (optionally you could repeat this action multiple times, having a *wait X seconds* between these actions-without *wait*, they would all play nearly at same time)

     (OR)
   - *Choose File* - You can save a  sound clipping of your choice  and length on your phone, say in your internal memory and navigate to it by `/storage /sdcard0 /soundfile_saved location`.
   - *Click OK*

**Constraints:** None

- **Reverse for other callers macro** ( for reverting to existing setup for other callers, meaning those who haven't blocked caller ID)

**Trigger**: *Call incoming* → *Select contact* →*Any number* ( By specifying this, it is applicable to contacts and non-contacts who haven't barred their caller ID )

Only one action in this macro is that of *Volume Change* as above but with **opposite** settings of muting *music* and reverting *ringer* to original

**Constraints:** None

**Note**

1. For reverting the changes made in the first macro, we have two options:

   a)  Reverting after a time period of choice

   b)  Reverting based on caller identity

Second option is chosen and implemented since time based option can produce unwanted results like successive caller ID barred calls, with the second  one ( *if* ) outside the time limit would be wrongly treated

2. Since I cannot verify with blocked ID calls (not being allowed in my country ), I set the first macro for known mobile contact (and predefined sound instead of saved clip ) and second macro for known landline and it worked. Do let me know if any clarifications or problems arise
3. **Edit:** I am running KitKat and you are on Lollipop. There is a difference in how  sounds are treated (example below)

Google Voice Recognition functionality that creates the "ding" sound when activated was streamed as notification stream  in KitKat. In Lollipop this is switched to music  stream.

**Source**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701432/continues-speech-recognition-beep-sound-after-google-search-update

I am not aware if *Ringer* sounds also changed, though unlikely. If the macros don't work because of such a change, you may need to change *system sounds option similar to music in both macro actions*