# Turn off vibration on apps for nexus

Tags: nexus-4

Is there any way to turn off the vibration on the nexus 4 phone? I would like to open up the phone and rip out the vibration device it is annoying me that much.

For all calls and SMS there is no vibration. But for the Apps there is vibration. However I would like to keep the notifications for the apps, in the sense that I would like to have the visual pop ups that come on the screen. They are great! But it seems like it is almost impossible to decouple the associated vibrations that come with it.

If I go to the app notifications it either gives me the option of completely getting rid of the notifications, or having the notifications with vibrate. Only WhatsApp has the little cog wheel at the top which gives me the option of turning off vibration as well. All other apps don't.

Otherwise can someone tell me where this vibrate thingy is so I can jam a screwdriver into it or pour acid into it?

Comment: Try [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) -easy to learn automation tool. Macro would be **Trigger:**  Notification>Notification Received>from any app>text any **Action:** Vibrate Disable /Enable>Vibrate off **Constraints**None. To understand how MacroDroid works and required **settings**, [see this](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/133394/131553)