# Custom notifications for contacts

Tags: notifications, automation

I'm looking to create a group of users on my phone that would have custom notification relative to my volume setting on my phone. This group of user's text message should cause my phone to vibrate when my phone is muted, vibrate when my phone is on vibrate, and ring when my phone volume is on.

Comment: I have a somewhat similar macro running on my device (on KitKat) , tweaked it a bit and posted solution.

Comment: Your Android device and version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automation is the preferred option. Many apps are available. I prefer using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) , since it is free (upto 5 macros) and easy to learn. To understand how MacroDroid works and required **settings**,  my [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133394/131553)

Your macros would look like this

- **Important SMS** (name of macro )

**Trigger**: *SMS Received* → *SMS from (select contacts)* →*SMS content (any)*

**Actions**:

1. *Vibrate* →  *Select vibration option*

   - Long press on above action  and select *Add Constraints → Ringer Volume → Vibrate or Silent*
2. . *Ringtone Configure* →  *Select Ringtone option*

   - Long press on above action  and select *Add Constraints → Ringer Volume → Volume on*

**Constraints:** None

**Note:** Action 2 not tested, since I need incoming text for that and don't have a device for that

[image]