# Stop vibrate for incoming calls and text messages from certain contacts

Tags: vibration

For certain contacts, I want to silence vibration for incoming calls and SMS messages.

I am **not** asking about silencing the *audio* notification and ringtone.  This is already well documented.

Answer (score 2):

Automation is the preferred option. Many apps are available. I prefer using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) , since it is free (upto 5 macros) and easy to learn. To understand how MacroDroid works and required **settings**,  my [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133394/131553)

---

Your macros would look like this

- **Macro 1: Kill Vibration** (name of macro )

**Triggers**:

1. *Call incoming* → *Select contact* →*Choose from contacts*
2. *SMS received* → *Select contact* →*Choose from contacts*

**Actions**:

*Vibrate Enable/ Disable* →  *Set Vibrate* and set *Normal (Vibrate off)*. Click *OK*

**Constraints:** None (leave blank)

- **Macro 2: Enable Vibration for others** (name of macro )

**Triggers**:

1. *Call incoming* → *Select contact* →*Choose from contacts*
2. *SMS received* → *Select contact* →*Choose from contacts*

**Actions**:

*Vibrate Enable/ Disable* →  *Set Vibrate* and set *Silent (Vibrate on)*. Click *OK*

**Constraints:** None (leave blank)

**Explanation**

1. Your question **explicitly** asks only for vibration to be silenced (but ring tone would be heard)
2. Macro 1 does that for both incoming calls and SMS for selected contacts
3. Macro 2 does the opposite for contacts other than selected in Macro 1 (you have to choose others- if you don't reverse Macro 1 action, vibration would be *off* for all)
4. Tested on Moto X Play Marshmallow (6.0.1)