# Lenovo Vibe P1 display toggles on and off while charging

Tags: charging, screen, lenovo, lenovo-vibe-p1

I have a Lenovo Vibe and using it from a year and a half. Recently I observed that the display turns *on* and *off* on it's own, while charging (only while charging)

I tried to change Display Settings and upgrading the device. But the problem still persists. So even if I charge for 3 hours, it fills only for 50 %. This was not the behaviour earlier.

How can I fix this please?

Current Android Version: 5.1. I don't remember the previous version .

Comment: How can I update my question ? Didn't see any options. So adding a comment.I don't remember the previous version. Here's the current details.

Android Version: 5.1
Base band version: P1ma40_A_V035_160226

Comment: Where i can find developer option ? In settings tab, i don't see it. I have only "About Phone" 
And I didn't understand the term, " Rooted"

Comment: @Vijay to update your question, use the [edit] link below it. As for developer settings: If you don't see them, you can't have changed that option (and btw, it wouldn't explain the turning on *and off)*. If you're interested in this nevertheless, see our [usb-debugging tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/usb-debugging/info) on how to activate developer settings ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* a solution to fix your device problem. It is a workaround only to keep your screen off, while charging

Automation is the preferred option. Many apps are available. I prefer using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) , since it is free (upto 5 macros) and easy to learn. To understand how MacroDroid works and required **settings**,  my [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133394/131553)

---

Your macro would look like this

- **Macro : Screen Off** (name of macro )

**Trigger**:

*Power Connected*

**Action**:

*Screen On/Off* →  *Screen Off*

**Constraints:** None (leave blank)

Comment: I will try this Work around and let you know the results. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If the answer meets your needs, you can consider "accepting" it by ticking the green check mark on the left. This shows it worked for you and also those seeking in future for a similar solution will find it useful