# Turn off the notification sound at system level - Android Marshmallow

Tags: notifications, audio

I have an OPO 3 and I was wondering if there is a possibility to turn off the notification sound for all app, but I would like to retain ringtone sound as well as vibration.

Normally on Samsung S6, there's a possibility to do this when you press the <kbd>Volume</kbd> rocker key.

My device is rooted and have Xposed installed. I tried [Ringer & Notification Volume unlink](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.gzplanet.xposed.ringerandnotificationvolumeunlink) xposed module but that doesn't seem to work.

This is something that I miss very badly, it's tragic that google didn't encompass this feature by default.

Comment: Try [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid)  1. Trigger: application launched ( choose few to start with) 2. Actions: notification sound - none 3. Constraints None..see if it works for you

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks for the reply. That actually did the job. Can you add the comment above as an answer below, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automation is the preferred option. Many apps are available. I prefer using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) , since it is free (upto 5 macros) and easy to learn. To understand how MacroDroid works and required **settings**,  my [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133394/131553)

---

Your macro would look like this

- **Macro : Kill Notification** (name of macro )

**Trigger**:  *Application Launched* ( choose from the drop down the apps for which you want the macro to run)

**Action**: *Notification Sound*  ( select none, since you don't want any)

**Constraints:** *None* ( which means this macro *always runs* whenever chosen apps are launched)