# Turn off notice sound

Tags: notifications, audio

I keep on getting audio notice alerts when the apps alerts me on posters updates; where do I go to keep the notice alerts silent?

Comment: See [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/155754/131553).  Select the app you wish to silence. Let me know how it goes