# How to ignore a call?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, calls

When someone calls me and I don't want to pick up nor reject (sending to voicemail), I silence the ringing and have to wait until the ringing is over before I can use my phone again (the screen is stuck on showing me that I'm getting a phone call).

I want to be able to both silence the call and get back to what I was doing immediately, even if the other side is still ringing. Is this possible?

I'm on a Samsung S7 Edge with Android 6.0.1.

Comment: Just an idea - try to press Home button.

Comment: @Alex.S I did (along with every physical button on the device) and it doesn't work.

Comment: Try "Call Control- Call Blocker". It is on the play store and my friend say's it works like a charm.

Comment: Did the Macrodroid solution not help?

Comment: @beeshyams Not sure yet :P I'm waiting to see if there's any native solution, which would of course be more preferable. I don't think one is going to come though, unfortunately. I'm a bit wary of Macrodroid being an overkill but I'll try it as soon as I have the time. Thanks a lot for your help by the way. It's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) , easy to learn automation app can help you

You can create a *macro* as below to

- Reject calls
- Create customisable SMS to let the callers know reason for rejection

[image]
[image]

To activate the macro you have two choices :

- In *Constraints* add the condition you want the macro to run, like day of the week or time of day
- From the app *widget* . Select the widget, drop it on to your home screen and assign this macro to the widget. You would then be able to manually enable / disable the macro if the earlier option is not suitable

To understand how MacroDroid works and required **settings**,  my [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133394/131553)