# Setting a reminder for when you enter your car

Tags: accessibility, nfc, android-auto, google-keep, reminders

Most of us have Android smartphones. At the same time, not all of us may have Android powered(/enabled) cars, but, may have to do something (such, as, check a note in the front drawer, or under the top light blocking panes, or do something next to the engine or other car part in the front hood, or grab something in the back part of the car and give it to someone in the morning, or check the fueling components at the back or at the front, or clear the back seat, or something along these lines).

Google Keep has location reminders, but here we need something to remind us when we get in proximity of the car. And we may not be able to go to the car, because we may be busy or it may be snowing outside.

We want to set a reminder that kicks in as a notification next time we are in proximity of the car, perhaps also with a specific associated time or time interval in which that reminder will be active.

Does NFC do the job? Do I need to purchase a special NFC chip for my car, and how can I program it make the notification kick in when my phone is next to the car or when I enter the car. Can NFC be made to work this way?

How can I do this in Android?

Thank you for your contributions.

Thanks.

Comment: Something like [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/160971/131553) When connected to car Bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

you need to give more informations to help us understand and then help you.

When you say 'next time we are in proximity of the car' what kind of proximity is it ?

NFC could be a solution but the max range of it is 10 - 15 cm so you would need to be really close.

I would recommend using wifi (15 to 45 meter range)or ble (bluetooth low energy | max range 100m).

You could setup a ble device broadcasting auround the car and have an android app on your phone to "catch" the broadcast.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do such devices exist. If so, then can you please post a link in your answer? Thanks.

Comment: I don’t know. i thought you could make your own solution by making an android application. Another way to go could be using AirTags but I don’t know how they broadcast.