# How to block all apps notification except sms and calls?

Tags: notifications, notification-bar

By accident I made a reset to all apps notifications, and suddenly I have a machine gun of notifications popping up on the phone. Please, I know it's a smartphone, but it's still a phone and I merely want to be notified with phone issues: sms and calls.

How can I block all apps notification, from sounds and in status bar, except sms and calls, without going individually to each of one?

Comment: Do you want to block just sound or block even appearing of notifications in status bar? If you want to block sounds of app except calls and sms you can do that with do not disturb and set priority to calls and sms. If you want to block appearing of notifications you can do it with Tasker (I think so) but I'm not really familiar with it, otherwise you always can block it one by one from settings.

Comment: I mean also notifications in status bar. I'll edit accordingly

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with  [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) automation app (free upto 5 macros) and real easy to learn

**Trigger:** Notification → Notification Received  → Select app  → Text content  → Any  → `ok`

**Action:** Clear Notifications  → choose apps from drop down (don't use *clear all*, since it has phone and SMS )→ `ok` Text content  → Any  → `ok`

**Constraints:** Leave blank

Name the macro , save and you are safe from *machine gun fire* :)

Comment: If your device is rooted, you can *Configure App Notifications* individually or collectively

Comment: Quick primer on app [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133394/131553)

Answer (score 1):

I used the application [Notifications Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff) (you need root access). It is straightforward and simple. You simply uncheck all apps and then tick only call and sms apps.