# How do I prevent GPS location being enabled automatically on Android 8.0.0

Tags: gps, gps-tracking

The GPS is sporadically enabled on my phone without my consent or even a notification. I have to keep an eye on it and turn it off when I notice it's on. Is there a "global" setting I can use to prevent this or at least ensure I get a notification when it's about to be enabled?

Comment: Depending on your Android version and device you can usually check the last apps that have accessed your location in Settings -> Security -> Location

Comment: There seems to be a great variation across Android/device versions. I found a switch under Settings->Connections->Location which is currently turned off. I'll take a look at this next time GPS comes on-I haven't explicitly enabled this myself.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you sure this is specifically a GPS lock request, not just any location service request (e.g. WiFi, Bluetooth, cellular network)? Also, mentioning the device model might help.

Comment: @Andrew T. The GPS symbol is highlighted when this occurs and I have to explicitly disable it in settings. Device model is Samsung Note 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[automation](/questions/tagged/automation) as suggested in comment  seems to come close to what OP wants.

Many automation apps are available. I prefer using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) , since it is free (upto 5 macros) and easy to learn. To understand how MacroDroid works and required **settings**,  my [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133394/131553)

---

Your macro would look like this

- **Macro : GPS on Alert** (name of macro )

**Trigger**: *GPS enabled/disabled* →*GPS enabled *

**Actions**:

- *Display Notification* → Enter the desired text. I suggest you choose hour, minute and second to pinpoint the exact time
- *Speak text* - enter the desired text

**Constraints**: None ( Macro runs always )

This will not tell you when it is *about* to be enabled but tells you *after* it is enabled.

Once you have the time stamp, use an app or other methods suggested in [logging](/questions/tagged/logging) & [logcat](/questions/tagged/logcat) to try and pinpoint the app causing it (read their tag wiki's by clicking on learn more). Disable or uninstall such app(s)