# Call someone automatically after receiving an app notification

Tags: applications, calls, automation, push-notifications, intents

I'm fairly new to android, I just want to know if it is possible to implement a feature on an app that when you would receive a push notification it will call a specific number or send a sms.

Ive been searching through this site and what I found most similar to this it involves clicking on the notification so that it makes the call afterwards but not right away automatically as soon as you receive notification.

So the objective would be something like this: a cellphone or tablet is awaiting for a push notification from an app at night when it  receives push notification it sends a sms or call to another cellphone which could be mine or someone else, is ti something doable that call intents can do this automatically without you having to interact with the device that will receive the push notification?

Comment: Possible by [tag:automation]. Try with [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid). Set up a macro like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeIEv.jpg), test and revert

Comment: To understand how MacroDroid works , see  [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133394/131553)

Comment: Hi and welcome, note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users or power-users (but not necessarily developers) solving their issues, so we will only provide solution from end-users' point of view, e.g. using automation apps or specialized 3rd-party apps.

Comment: Did you try automation?