# How can I configure WhatsApp so that an email is sent to me when someone sends me a message on WhatsApp?

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, email

How can I configure WhatsApp so that an email is sent to me when someone sends me a message on WhatsApp?

Comment: You can also tell those people using Whatsapp that you prefer to receive messages via E-Mail.

Answer (score 5):

Whatsapp natively does not support this, besides, it does not expose an API for other apps to use, so it's not possible. But using the notifications generated on receipt of messages, one can workaround these limitations.

[automation](/questions/tagged/automation) is the way to go because, you need an action to be taken  in case WhatsApp is received from one / any senders.

Many automation apps are available. I prefer using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) , since it is *free* (upto 5 macros) and easy to learn. To understand how MacroDroid works, see [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133394/131553) (Not affiliated to any app).

**MacroDroid Setup**

- Give MacroDroid all the permissions it needs.
- From Settings → Email account → Gmail account. Enter your account details and authenticate (MacroDroid needs to have access to be able to send you mails). Edit: As pointed out by a user you may need to use [APP passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) instead of regular email password.

Create a macro as explained, name it whatever you like and save it.

- **Trigger:** Notification → Notification Received → Select Application → Whatsapp → Text Content → Any (this will mail you for **all** messages received)

Make sure to *uncheck* prevent
multiple triggers (Edit:  As pointed out by a user if you get duplicate emails a fix could be, by *checking* multiple triggers YMMV)

A variant below for **one** contact

Notification → Notification Received → Select Application → Whatsapp → Text Content → Matches (or contains) → contact name (you can use wild cards or [Regular expressions(Regex)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)
matching too)

- **Actions:** Send Email → account → Email address (where you want the mail to be sent to) → Subject, copy paste

`Whatsapp message from [not_title] at  [hour12].[minute][am_pm]`

Message Text, copy paste `[notification]`

You will get mails with sender name, time stamp and text<sup>see note</sup> as in screenshot below (`Aa` is a contact and I configured for a single sender)

[image]

Note:

1. Email  shows the text in notification, which may not be complete text, because Notifications are restricted to 500 characters . Long texts are truncated (in my tests text till *see more* was mailed).
2. Notifications need to be enabled for Whatsapp