# How to receive email when missing or receiving call or sms?

Tags: sms, calls, email, alerts

I have a couple of phones with their own sim cards and provider (for many different reasons) and so, given I don't want to:

- Hear different ringtones
- Hear the same ringtones but multiplied
- Monitor all of those different sim cards/phone
- etc

I thought of knowing how to get/receive alerts through email when receiving or/and missing phone calls and (if possible) SMS...

Is there an application existing for this? or some sort of setup? I'm well aware of the reverse existing (eg: sending phone calls/SMS for email) but after searching for a while, I didn't find much if anything that would do the above.

Any advice/answer/feedback is welcome. I'm on the latest android (but I don't mind using the older version).

Comment: User [tag:automation] // with [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) set up a macro with trigger :missed call and actions 1.send email 2. Send sms//configure your email in settings

Comment: That's *Nice*...How come I never heard of this before? Thanks!

Comment: This [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/226505/131553) is somewhat related

Comment: Yeah, but don't think mine is a duplicate given this is mainly about "direct" phone calls (eg: without whatsapp etc) and sms notification through email..But it is somewhat related yeah @beeshyams

Comment: That was just to give some pointers (not a dupe) //In my first comment I addressed missed calls only //you can tackle sms similar way, I have  SMS portion set up on my phone for selected originators (Bank etc)